# USB Midi driver for Android crashes

Tags: android, midi

I am trying to use this USB-MIDI-Driver https://github.com/kshoji/USB-MIDI-Driver in my project. I added the driver using gradle,

```
maven {url 'https://github.com/kshoji/USB-MIDI-Driver/raw/master/MIDIDriver/snapshots'}
...
compile 'jp.kshoji:midi-driver:0.1.1:@aar'
```

copied the sample (https://github.com/kshoji/USB-MIDI-Driver/blob/master/MIDIDriverSample/src/jp/kshoji/driver/midi/sample/UsbMidiDriverSampleActivity.java), removed the "play audio" part and started the activity from my MainActivity.

My problem is, that with time it gets slower and slower, it misses events, I skip frames, the ui becomes unresponsive, the device is detatched and my app crashes more or less... The pre-compiled project from Google Play Market works fine though.

The only thing I can think of is that I use the wrong version of the driver or sample... Is there anyone who had a similar problem and can help me?

Comment: Using the android device monitor I discovered that the cpu load explodes when I run the code... does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not really find an answer but followed [kshojis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2005954/kshoji) comment in [Send MIDI messages over USB on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102850/send-midi-messages-over-usb-on-android?rq=1) and tried the alternative driver he suggests (http://www.humatic.de/htools/nmj/).

nmj seems to use much less resources  but requires you to interpret midi-events. http://www.petesqbsite.com/sections/express/issue18/midifilespart1.html is a nice resource on how to read midi.