# TCP/IP client incorrectly reading inputstream byte array

Tags: java, tcp, client

I'm creating a Java Client program that sends a command to server and server sends back an acknowledgement and a response string.

> The response is sent back in this manner
>
> ```
> client -> server : cmd_string
>
> server -> client : ack_msg(06)
>
> server -> client : response_msg
> ```

**Client code**

public static void readStream(InputStream in) {

```
    byte[] messageByte = new byte[20];// assuming mug size -need to
                                        // know eact msg size ?
    boolean end = false;
    String dataString = "";
    int bytesRead = 0;

    try {
        DataInputStream in1 = new DataInputStream(in);
        // while ctr==2 todo 2 streams
        int ctr = 0;
        while (ctr < 2) {//counter 2 if ACK if NAK ctr=1 todo
            bytesRead = in1.read(messageByte);

            if (bytesRead > -1) {
                ctr++;
            }
            dataString += new String(messageByte, 0, bytesRead);

            System.out.println("\ninput byte arr "+ctr);
            for (byte b : messageByte) {
                char c=(char)b;
                System.out.print(" "+b);
            }
        }


        System.out.println("MESSAGE: " + dataString + "\n bytesread " + bytesRead + " msg length "
                + dataString.length() + "\n");
        char[] chars = dataString.toCharArray();
        ArrayList<String> hex=new ArrayList<>();
        // int[] msg ;
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            int val = (int) chars[i];
            System.out.print(" " + val);
        hex.add(String.format("%04x",  val));
        }
        System.out.println("\n"+hex);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // ===

}
```

**Output**

```
    client Socket created .. 
     response:

     input byte arr 1
     6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    input byte arr 2
     2 -77 67 79 -77 48 -77 3 -116 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    MESSAGE: ##³CO³0³##
     (where # is some not supported special character )
     bytesread 9 msg length 10

     dec: 6 2 179 67 79 179 48 179 3 338
    hex: [0006, 0002, 00b3, 0043, 004f, 00b3, 0030, 00b3, 0003, 0152]
    bytes: 2 -77 67 79 -77 48 -77 3 -116 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 (bytes recieved in 2nd packet)
    connection closed
```

> **Problem:** I'm reading the last value incorrect, I have verified using wireshark the server has sent back the response as  06 02 b3 43
>   4f b3 30 b3 03 8c
>
> Some how I'm reading the last value in correctly. Is there some issue with the reading stream?

**EDIT**

Rest of the response is read correctly but the last character should be 8c But is read as 0152Hex

Response from server :  06 02 b3 43 4f b3 30 b3 03 8c

Read by program : [0006, 0002, 00b3, 0043, 004f, 00b3, 0030, 00b3, 0003, 0152]

issue with reading the last character

**EDIT 2**

**Response is received as 2 packets/streams**

```
packet 1 byte arr :  6 (ACK)

packet 2 byte arr:  2 -77 67 79 -77 48 -77 3 -116 (response)
```

**complete response read by client**

```
  dec: 6 2 179 67 79 179 48 179 3 338
  hex: [0006, 0002, 00b3, 0043, 004f, 00b3, 0030, 00b3, 0003, 0152]
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried directly inspecting the bytesRead, without converting to String and back? Maybe its just an encoding issue.

Comment: @HenkDeBoer I have posted the byte arrat aswell.

Comment: In 8-bit arithmetic, hex 8C and decimal -116 are the same value. So you read the right value, you just converted it to the wrong representation.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz can you please explain how should I convert ? I'm new to these concepts .

Comment: @RachitaNanda It's not clear what you are trying to do. Also, your code can't produce the output you show. So it's hard for me to tell exactly what the issue is. But as a start, stop converting into and through signed types.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz can you please suggest alternate methods that do not involve signed types. Thank you

Comment: So the byte array shows 9 values, but the server sent 10? Are you sure you arent counting TCP status codes with wireshark aswell?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  I have update my code and output , the input is recieved in 2 packets.Please see

Comment: Can you try doing (char c=(char)(b&0xFF);) instead of (char c=(char)b;). And then print the char c.

Comment: @RachitaNanda You read the right value, -116 decimal. You borked it after that, somehow turning it into 152 hex.

Comment: @HenkDeBoer  I changed the char arr using (char c=(char)(b&0xFF); and now I get the correct response. Can you please share why this needs to be done .Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this question was a matter of **signed** variables versus **unsigned** variables. When you have a number in computer memory, it is represented by a bunch of bits, each of them 0 or 1. Bytes are generally 8 bits, shorts are 16 etc. In an **unsigned** number, 8 bits will get you from positive 0 to 255, but not to negative numbers.

This is where **signed** numbers come in. In a signed number, the first bit tells you whether the following bits represent a negative or positive value. So now you can use 8 bits to represent -128 to +127. (Notice that the positive range is halved, from 255 to 127, because you "sacrifice" half of your range to the negative numbers).

So now what happens if you convert **signed** to **unsigned**? Depending on how you do it, things can go wrong. In the problem above, the code `char c=(char)b;` was converting a **signed** byte to an **unsigned** char. The proper way to do this is to "make your byte unsigned" before converting it to a char. You can do that like this: `char c=(char)(b&0xFF);` [more info on casting a byte here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966580/convert-unsigned-byte-to-signed-byte).

Essentially, you can just remember that except for char, all java numbers are signed, and all you need to do is paste the `&0xFF` to make it work for a byte, `0xFFFF` to make it work for a short, etc.

The details about why this works are as follows. Calling & means a [bitwise and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation), and `0xFF` is hexadecimal for 255. 255 is above the limit of a signed byte (127), so the number `b&0xFF` gets upgraded to a short by java. However, the short signed bit is on bit 16, while the byte signed bit is on bit 8. So now the byte signed bit becomes a normal 'data' bit in the short, and so the sign of your byte is essentially discarded.

If you do a normal cast, java recognizes that doing direct bitconversion like above would mean that you lose the sign, and java expects you don't like that (at least, that is my assumption), so it preserves the sign for you. So if this isn't what you want, you explicitly tell java what to do.