# Java can't recognize some bytes, it detects them as int?

Tags: java, android, byte

```
private static byte [] header = {0x16,0x98,0x01,0x02,0x14,0x01,0x00,0x02,0x10,0x03,0x03};
```

I have initialized one of my byte array in a java program. Here java showing one error, 0x98 need to be casted to byte externally. Why java showing this value is a int value ? And how to tell java that this is a byte ?

Comment: Not really a duplicate but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966580/convert-unsigned-byte-to-signed-byte)

Comment: Bytes are signed. 0x98 does not fit in a signed byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`byte` has a range from -128 to 127 (=0x7F). (See also https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_data_types.asp)

Therefore the maximum Hex-Number you can add to your byte-array is 0x7F. The next value 0x80 can be stored to `int` (4 byte) or others like `short` (2 byte)

Edit:

If you want to assign 0x98 to a byte-variable you can cast it to byte:

```
byte x = (byte) 0x98;
```

To print this value unsigned you can use `Byte.toUnsignedInt(x);`

```
System.out.println(x); //will print -104
System.out.println(Byte.toUnsignedInt(x)); //will print 152
```

Comment: what is the data type similar to unsigned byte ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but i think there is nothing similar to unsigned byte.
If you want to add 0x98 to your byte array you can write code like `byte x = (byte) 0x98`. 0x98 = -104 in that case. When you want to print the value of the byte, `System.out.println(x)` will print -104, if you want to print the unsigned value you can print it like that: `System.out.println(Byte.toUnsignedInt(x));`

Answer (score 2):

In Java, numerals are assumed to have the type `int`. So when you write `0x98`, this is assumed to be the `int` 152. If you write `0x03` it is assumed to be the `int` 3.

The byte type has values ranging from -128 ... 127. You can assign any `int` in this range to a variable constrained to hold `byte` variables without any issue.

But the number 152 is outside this range, so you get the error:

> incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte

You can write `(byte)0x98` to make it work.

In JShell:

```
jshell> 0x98
$1 ==> 152

jshell> (byte)0x98
$2 ==> -104
```

Comment: what is similar to unsigned byte in java ? is casting is a good solution ? I think java should handle this internally ?

Comment: Actually, Java does not have unsigned integral types. I don't think there is anything wrong with casting. It's the way Java is. You can't specify byte literals in the language, so just cast, it's fine. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5193883/831878

Answer (score 0):

The simplistic answer to this question is that `0x98` is not a byte.  Java bytes are signed and range from -128 to +127.  `0x98` is greater than +127.

But the real explanation starts with the FACT that *Java doesn't have byte literals at all*.  Every integer literal denotes either an `int` value or a `long` value.

So how does this work then?

```
 byte b = 1;
```

It works because there is a **special rule** that allows a *compile time constant expression* whose type is `int` to be assigned to a `byte` **if and only if** the value is in range of `byte`.  So the above works, but:

```
byte b2 = 0x98;  // ERROR
```

is rejected because `0x98` is outside of the range of `byte`.

And the same rule applies within array initializers.